# What is the quantum analog of classical infinitesimal displacement?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, special-relativity, metric-tensor, semiclassical

What is the quantum analog of classical infinitesimal displacement with Lorentz invariance? Where the classical infinitesimal displacement is given by:

$$ ds^2 = c^2 dt^2 - dr^2.$$

Comment: Why should there be such a thing? What does "analog" even mean here, given that abstract quantum mechanics doesn't, a priori, even *have* notions of space?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The object $\mathrm ds^2$ is not really an infinitesimal displacement, but a *metric*. In non-relativistic QM, the metric is the standard, Euclidian one
$$
\mathrm ds^2=\mathrm d\boldsymbol r^2
$$
so that, for example, the Laplacian in the Schrödinger equation is
$$
\Delta=-\frac{\partial}{\partial \boldsymbol r}\cdot\frac{\partial}{\partial\boldsymbol r}
$$
, as usual.

On the other hand, in relativistic QM, $\mathrm ds^2$ is the Minkowski metric,
$$\mathrm ds^2=\mathrm dt^2-\mathrm d\boldsymbol r^2$$
with Laplacian
$$
\Delta=\frac{\partial^2}{\partial t^2}-\frac{\partial}{\partial \boldsymbol r}\cdot\frac{\partial}{\partial\boldsymbol r}
$$
also known as d'Alambertian.

Finally, in QM in curved space-times, the metric is in principle arbitrary
$$
\mathrm ds^2=g_{\mu\nu}\mathrm dx^\mu\mathrm dx^\nu
$$

Comment: AccidentalFourierTransform: "_The object $ {\rm d}s^2$ is [...] a metric._" -- A [metric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_(mathematics)) is a function that defines a (generalized) distance between each pair of elements of a set; e.g. $$d : X \times X \rightarrow [0,\infty).$$ If you claim that ${\rm d}s^2$ is (or denotes) a metric, and that this metric might be expressed as product of the form $${\rm d}s^2=g_{\mu \nu}~\rm dx^{\mu}~\rm dx^{\nu},$$ how do these factors on the right-hand side (and among them especially the factror $g_{\mu \nu}$) depend on the requisite **pair of arguments**?

Comment: @user12262 $g_{\mu\nu}=\mathrm ds^2(\partial_\mu,\partial_\nu)$, as usual. I'm not sure what's your question though

Comment: AccidentalFourierTransform: If you claim that "_${\rm d}s^2$ is a metric_" then we should be able to write the function definition
$$ {\rm d}s^2 : X \times X \rightarrow \mathbb R.$$
What's the specific set $X$ to satisfy your claim? And: is ["identity of indiscernibles"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_(mathematics)) satisfied for this supposed "_metric_"?

Comment: @user12262 $X$ is the tangent space (at some point) of whatever manifold we are using. I mean, this is very standard differential geometry, I'm not "claiming" anything that cannot be found in the most basic books on the subject :-/

Comment: AccidentalFourierTransform: "_$X$ is the tangent space (at some point) of whatever manifold we are using._" -- Are the factors "${\rm d}x^{\mu}$", "${\rm d}x^{\nu}$" functions of a **pair of elements** of "_the tangent space (at some point)_", too? "_very standard differential geometry [...] found in the most basic books on the subject_" -- I bet. But here the question can be raised publicly whether this even fits [the definition of "metric"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_(mathematics)). (So: I plan to do that tomorrow.)

Comment: @user12262 "Metric" in differential geometry doesn't mean the same thing as in basic topology. However, every riemannian metric $g:\Gamma \left( {TM} \right) \times \Gamma \left( {TM} \right) \to {C^\infty }\left( M \right)$ (note that $g = {g_{\mu \nu }}{\operatorname{dx} ^\mu }{\operatorname{dx} ^\nu } = {\operatorname{ds} ^2}$) on a manifold M defines a metric $\operatorname{d} :M \times M \to \mathbb{R}$ by $\operatorname{d} \left( {p,q} \right) = \mathop {\inf }\limits_\gamma  \int\limits_p^q {\sqrt {g\left( {\dot \gamma ,\dot \gamma } \right)} }$ ,the gamma are paths from p to q.

Comment: @Jake: "_Metric" in diff. geom. doesn't mean the same thing as in basic topology._" -- Rather, it seems, some fail to acknowledge (or to understand) the distinction between "[metric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_(mathematics))" and "[metric **tensor**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_tensor)". "_However, every riemannian metric [tensor] $g$ [...] defines a metric $\rm d$_" -- Or the other way around: For a given metric space, it can be determined whether it's a "length space", which subsets are "paths", which paths are "[just touching](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1478959/)"...

Comment: AccidentalFourierTransform: As promised yesterday, my question has been submitted here: [_"Are metric tensors (or even pseudo-metric tensors) really metrics?"_ (pse/q/299701)](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/299701).

Comment: AccidentalFourierTransform: My question has meanwhile been migrated (as I learned from being notified) to [_"Are metric tensors (or even pseudo-metric tensors) really metrics?"_ (mse/q/2066741)](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/2066741). (@tfb's answer: "_The metric tensor $g$ [...] is not itself the distance function._" had already been accepted here; but it still seems to need some improvement on the details how, for example, a metric on the tangent space of a given manifold could be defined in terms of the metric tensor.)